# How to log on STDOUT and file using Play 2 and Akka

Tags: scala, logging, intellij-idea, playframework, akka

I'm trying to get logged Akka message on `STDOUT` and on `logs/application.log` with other loggers.

I'm using Play 2.3.7 + Akka 2.3.9 + Scala 2.11.6.

IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.1 using Scala 1.4.11 plugin.

I can't get logged Akka info neither on `logs/application.log` or `STDOUT` using this configuration:

Content of `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val akkaVersion = "2.3.9"
  Seq(
    jdbc,
    filters,
    "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-actor"    % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-slf4j"    % akkaVersion,
    "org.apache.spark"    %%  "spark-core"    % "1.3.0",
    "org.mariadb.jdbc"    %   "mariadb-java-client"    % "1.1.7",
    "mysql"               %   "mysql-connector-java"   % "5.1.12",
    "com.typesafe.play"   %%  "play-slick"             % "0.8.1",
    "joda-time"           %   "joda-time"              % "2.7",
    "org.joda"            %   "joda-convert"           % "1.7",
    "com.github.tototoshi"  %%  "slick-joda-mapper"    % "1.2.0",
    "org.jsoup"           %   "jsoup"                  % "1.8.1"
  )
}
```

Content of `conf/application.conf`:

```
# Root logger:
logger.root=ERROR
# Logger used by the framework:
logger.play=INFO
# Logger provided to your application:
logger.application=DEBUG
# Logger slick
logger.scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement=DEBUG

# Akka
# ~~~~~
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
  actor {
    debug {
      receive = on
      autoreceive = on
      lifecycle = on
      event-stream = on
      unhandled = on
      router-misconfiguration = on
    }
  }
  remote {
    log-sent-message = on
    log-received-message = on
  }
}
```

Content of `conf/application-logger.xml`:

```
<conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${application.home}/logs/application.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%level] [%date] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <!-- Dispatcher: [%thread] -->
        <pattern>[%level] [%date] [%logger] %message%n%xException{5}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="play" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="application" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="akka" level="DEBUG" />

<!-- Off these ones as they are annoying, and anyway we manage configuration ourself -->
<logger name="com.avaje.ebean.config.PropertyMapLoader" level="OFF" />
<logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.XmlConfigLoader" level="OFF" />
<logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.BackgroundThread" level="OFF" />
<logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript" level="OFF" />

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

If I change `akka.loggers = ["akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger"]` in `conf/application.conf` removing `akka.logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"`, I can get log info only on `STDOUT`.

In actors I'm using this PoC:

```
class MyActor(var a : String) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  log.debug("Test " + a)
  ...
}
```

While outside in Play I'm using this PoC:

```
Logger.info("Intercept: " + request + "\n\t => " + result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989474/akka-actor-logging-not-writing-to-file) is a good example to follow.

It proposes to use this configuration:

```
akka {
  event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
}
```

Comment: Using this configuration I get logs only on ```STDOUT```, I'm trying to get logged also on file.